# Why Unknown column in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql

The following codes work well:

```
select session_id
from playback
where session_id not in 
    (select session_id
     from playback a join ads b
     on timestamp between start_time and end_time
     and a.customer_id = b.customer_id)
```

I tried to change the following part in subquery:

```
 join on timestamp between start_time and end_time
    and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

to

```
 join on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
 having b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.end_time
```

but got error as: `Unknown column 'b.timestamp' in 'having clause'`

What's the problem using having() here?

Comment: Instead you want the `ON` and `AND` keyword: `FROM playback a JOIN ads b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.end_time` as `HAVING` is a keyword for working with conditions on aggregate results (like WHERE, but after a GROUP BY has done it's magic).

Comment: Having is an extension to a group by (usually) you probably just need AND

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens when you have Having without using Group By.

I haven't had time to test these, but here are three possible ways that you could rewrite your statements:

#### Without group by

```sql
select session_id
from playback
where session_id not in 
    (select distinct a.session_id
     from playback as a 
          join ads as b
     on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
     where b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.end_time
)
```

#### With group by

```sql
select session_id
from playback
where session_id not in 
    (select a.session_id
     from playback as a 
          join ads as b
     on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
     group by a.session_id
     having b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.end_time
)
```

#### By not using subquery

```sql
select distinct a.session_id
from playback as a
left join ads as b
on b.customer_id = a.customer_id
where a.timestamp not between start_time and end_time
and b.customer_id is not null
```

Comment: Thank you! For the third method, why we need to have b.customer_id is not null as one of the conditions?

Comment: For some reason, the third method is not working, I found a similar way which is working well. But I don't understand why this one works while yours don't:                                                                                                          
SELECT session_id
FROM playback pb LEFT JOIN ads ad
ON pb.customer_id = ad.customer_id
AND ad.timestamp BETWEEN start_time and end_time
WHERE ad.customer_id IS NULL

Comment: b.customer_id is not null, makes it so that you only return things that truely match your on statement...

Comment: Oh that's awesome that you have a similar way! I'm going to try to figure out what I messed up by creating some data to go with this query :)

Comment: I found the issue :) I put the timestamp comparison in the where clause, I meant to place that in the ON statement! I'm glad I could help you out! I'm glad that you caught that in my example code, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that we found together on this journey:

```sql
SELECT session_id 
FROM playback pb 
LEFT JOIN ads ad 
ON pb.customer_id = ad.customer_id 
AND ad.timestamp 
BETWEEN start_time and end_time 
WHERE ad.customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: In general, it is frowned upon to answer a question more than once. Either make this answer a community wiki by editing your question and checking the community wiki box, or move this to your other answer and delete this answer.

Comment: why we require the condition: WHERE ad.customer_id IS NULL